# How to fetch specified data based on two columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to writing queries in SQL, and struggling to get the datas from table.

I have a table called "address" in DB. Here, I have more columns and specifically from two column I need to get the datas filtered out. Both are integers

1. frequency_type_id
2. date_of_invoice_id

   [image]

I need to get rows only where frequency_type_id = 1 and date_of_invoice_id=2, and frequency_type_id = 2 and date_of_invoice_id=3, frequency_type_id = 3 and date_of_invoice_id=1.

I am trying with the following query, but its not filtering properly,

```
SELECT address_id, company_name,  
invoice_batch_billing, frequency_type_id,  date_of_invoice_id
FROM pls.address where invoice_style='Consolidated' 
and frequency_type_id in 
(SELECT frequency_type_id from  pls.address where frequency_type_id=1 and date_of_invoice_id=1);
```

Hope someone assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query:

```
SELECT address_id, company_name,  
invoice_batch_billing, frequency_type_id,  date_of_invoice_id
FROM pls.address where invoice_style='Consolidated' 
and ((frequency_type_id=1 and date_of_invoice_id=2) or (frequency_type_id=2 and date_of_invoice_id=2) or (frequency_type_id=3 and date_of_invoice_id=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    address_id, 
    company_name,
    invoice_batch_billing,
    frequency_type_id,
    date_of_invoice_id
FROM 
    pls.address
WHERE
    frequency_type_id IN (1,2,3) 
AND 
    date_of_invoice_id=2
```

If I have understand your question correctly, this will suffice your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. This is fine for same date_of_invoice_id. If there is change in the value of date_of_invoice_id like 1 for frequency_type_id. This works?